# FullCalendar jQuery plug-in fires ajax events for every event (hover, mouseover, resize, ect...) when lazyFetching is set to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar to display events, which I'm getting through a javascript function that makes an AJAX call. This is done to send a limiter on how many events to pass back for a given day, with a ViewMore option included.

By turning off lazyFetching, the result seems to be that FullCalendar does a re-render for every event that's fired on the page. This results in it doing a new AJAX call each time.

How can I prevent FullCalendar from making these unnecessary AJAX calls?

below is the code for initializing my fullCalendar. Thanks!

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'basicWeek',
    theme: true,
    isRTL: isRightToLeft,
    contentHeight: 800,
    weekends: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    lazyFetching: false,
    columnFormat: {
        month: 'ddd',
        week: 'ddd ' + shortMonthDayPattern,
        day: 'dddd ' + shortMonthDayPattern
    },
    titleFormat: {
        month: yearMonthPattern,                             // September 2009
        week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}", // Sep 7 - 13 2009
        day: longDatePattern                  // Tuesday, Sep 8, 2009
    },
    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        if (view.name != 'basicDay') {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
        }
    },
    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
        if (event.id === "viewMore") {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', event.start);
        }
        else {
            navigateBackboneCal(event.id);
        }
    },
    editable: false,
    loading: function (isLoading) {
        if (isLoading) {
            $('.fc-content').block({
                message: null,
                css: { top: '10' }
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.fc-content').unblock();
        }
    },
    viewDisplay: function (view) {

    },
    events: function (startDt, endDt, callback) {
        var maxEvents = 0;
        var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
        if (view.name === 'month')
            maxEvents = 5;
        else if (view.name === 'basicWeek')
            maxEvents = 30;

        var events = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: '/GetCalendarEvents',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { start: Math.round(startDt.getTime() / 1000), end: Math.round(endDt.getTime() / 1000), maxEvents: maxEvents },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('There was an error while fetching events!');
                $('.fc-content').unblock();
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.viewMoreEvents)
                    events = $.merge(result.events, result.viewMoreEvents);
                callback(events);
            }
        });


    }
});
```